# AdMob crash after interstitial on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, admob

I'm developing my app using Adobe AIR, Starling, and Milkman's AdMob ANE extension. I've been implementing AdMob following the provided documentation without any issues and getting it to work properly.

Unfortunately some testers oversea noticed that AdMob crashes after displaying an interstitial. Oddly enough it seems AdMob is regularly crashing after "Game of War" playable interstitial.

We tried to test that even on a simple app with just a play button to show the interstitial and we still get the crash. The app is basically freezing with no further action.

This is very annoying, I tried to contact Milkman's support but I fear this might be a problem with AdMob itself. My guess is that some interstitial ads cause the crash.

Have you ever run into similar issues? Would you recommend any solution?

Thanks,
Gionathan

Comment: capture logs and post it in your question.... also post your admob code

Comment: PS: _"We tried to test that even on a simple app with just a play button to show the interstitial and we still get the crash"_ show others the **minimum code required to re-create your issue**.